# Append a string to a variable value

Tags: java, logging

I have in a.properties the following initialization :

```
log4j.appender.LogFile.File=../log/${log.file}
```

In order to use one more log I have to add the line :

```
log4j.appender.LogReport.File=../log/$(echo ${log.file}_report)
```

LogReport should use a file that has "_report" added to first log file name. Until now I have also tried:

```
log4j.appender.LogReport.File=../log/${log.file}_report
log4j.appender.LogReport.File=${log.file}_report
log4j.appender.LogReport.File=${log.file}+'report'
log4j.appender.LogReport.File=${log.file}+"report"
```

but no one worked as expected.

Comment: Did you try `log4j.appender.LogReport.File=../log/${log.file}_report.log` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${log}_report
```

that should work

Comment: Are you sure about this ? As far as I know, there should be a $ before starting the expression :)

Comment: yea I am sorry, I missed that.